# jQuery repeat action on field change

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery function to uncheck radios (with id #radio_range_[any]) AND check radio (with id #an) when i start typing in text field (id #custom_range_duration)

```
$('#custom_range_duration').bind('keypress keyup blur', function() {
  if ($('#custom_range_duration').val().length != 0){
    $('input[id^="radio_range_"]').attr('checked', false);
    $('#an').attr('checked', true);
  }
});
```

When i load page and start typing in field, #radio_range_ unchecks, #and checks successfuly. However when i check #radio_range_ range again AND start typing in field - then #radio_range_ unchecks, but #an does not check again.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you make a stack snippet that contains the HTML and demonstrates the problem? BTW, I recommend using a class instead of an ID prefix selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work the second time, is because jQuery checks the **property**, and you're changing the **attribute**, there's a difference.

You want to always use `prop()` when changing the checked state programatically

```
$('#custom_range_duration').bind('keypress keyup blur', function() {
    if ($('#custom_range_duration').val().length != 0) {
        $('input[id^="radio_range_"]').prop('checked', false);
        $('#an').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```